# Flatten a nested list structure using concatMap gives error

Tags: haskell

**Problem 7** *from 99 Haskell problems*

*Flatten a nested list structure*

This is my solution:

```hs
data NestedList a = Elem a | List [NestedList a]

myFlatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
myFlatten (Elem x) = [x]
myFlatten (List (x:xs)) = x : concatMap myFlatten xs
```

However, I would like to understand...Why does the compiler say:

> Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ NestedList a

> Expected type: [NestedList a]
> Actual type: [a]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine this part of the code, only:

```
myFlatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
myFlatten (List (x:xs)) = x : ...
```

Inside `List` we have `x:xs`, and by definition of `List` we find `(x:xs) :: [NestedList a]`. Hence:

```
x :: NestedList a
xs :: [NestedList a]
```

The returned value is `x : ...` and that is a list of the type of `x`, which is `NestedList a`. Hence, the return type is `[NestedList a]`.

However, the signature of `myFlatten` says that the return type is `[a]`. This is possible only if `[a] = [NestedList a]`, i.e. only if `a = NestedList a`, but that's impossible, hence the type error.

Comment: Thank you so much. It’s clear, now. Could you explain why `map flatten xs` instead of `concatMap flatten xs`, doesn’t work ?

Comment: @F.Zer `concatMap flatten xs` is equivalent to `concat (map flatten xs)`. Here, `map flatten xs` is a list-of-lists, but you instead want a list, hence the extra `concat`. It's the same difference between `[1]++[2]` and ``[[1],[2]]`, roughly put.

Comment: about your last explanation I have a question. You say: `map flatten xs` is a list-of-lists (sorry I called it myFlatten earlier). How do you know that expression is going to define a list of lists. Until now, `flatten` is not fully defined; only the case `Elem x` is defined. We should define what happens in the case `List xs`. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @F.Zer To deal with this kind of questions it is easier if you only look at types. Here, `flatten :: ... -> [a]` so it has to return a list. Hence `map flatten xs` must return a list-of-the-return-type-of-flatten, so a list of lists. The fact that we use that expression inside the definition of `flatten`, where `flatten` is not yet fully defined, does not matter.

Comment: That's an amazing explanation, @chi. Thank you. What happens if I leave out the type signature ? What would be the return type of `flatten` and, in turn, what would be the return type of `map flatten xs` ?

Comment: @F.Zer Without a type signature, GHC will try to infer the type from the code. The inference algorithm is not trivial, especially in recursive definitions, and can be a bit subtle in corner cases. If the code contains a bug, the inference might fail (if we're lucky) or (much worse) assign an unwanted type to `flatten`, which will later on cause puzzling type errors where we *correctly* call `flatten`. For that reason, adding a type signature is strongly recommended (and in the most complex cases where inference fails, even mandatory).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. I guess, in this particular case, the non-recursive case is inferred, and then the type of the recursive case (if valid) is correctly inferred. Is that right ? Without base case, the recursive case cannot be inferred, I think.

Comment: I’ll try to remember your advice about explicitly writing type signatures.

Comment: @F.Zer Actually, both cases are handled together during recursion: recursive calls roughly involve a special "unknown" type variable, and using that type constraints are generated, to be later on solved using a unification algorithm. You can find plenty of scientific papers on type inference, but it's not a straightforward topic. [Hindley-Milner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) is a basic inference algorithm, but nowadays much more complex ones are used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244756/discussion-between-f-zer-and-chi).

Answer (score 3):

With `List (x:xs)`, both `x` and `xs` are `NestedList a`s, not `a`s, you thus should use `concatMap` over the entire list, with:

```
myFlatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
myFlatten (Elem x) = [x]
myFlatten (List xs) = concatMap myFlatten xs
```

To avoid wrapping and unwrapping in singleton lists, you can work with a tail that you recursively pass to the list, with:

```
myFlatten :: NestedList a -> [a]
myFlatten = (`go` [])
    where go (Elem x) = (x :)
          go (List xs) = flip (foldr go) xs
```